# Non-compile time constants for DataTestMethods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

How can I use `[DataTestMethod]` in combination with `[DataRow(...)]` with non-compile-time constants? Example:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1), "2000-01-01")]
[DataRow(new DateTime(2000, 2, 1), "2000-02-01")]
public void TestTime(DateTime dateTime, string expected) {
    Assert.AreEqual(dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), expected);
    Assert.AreEqual(dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), expected);
}
```

This will throw a compile error on `new DateTime(...)` because this is not a compile-time constant.

Comment: On a side-note... what is the purpose of what you're actually trying to do here?

Comment: Unit testing for objects. The DateTime is simply an example. It should also be possible on more complex objects.
The xunit library is able to do this by passing the name of a method that returns an IEnumerable<T>. I was wondering if the MS unit tests also has this feature.

Comment: ms test has parameterized tests now? That's neat.  Not sure about MSTest, but it's very doable with NUnit through a `TestCaseSource`

Comment: You can use the `DynamicData` attribute instead of the `DataRow` attribute to specify a method or property to provide non-compile-time constant test data.

Comment: Thanks @steve16351, didn't know that this attribute existed and that seems to work. If you post is as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only specify compile-time constants in attributes, so you cannot directly provide the test method with non-constant data that way with `DataRow`. However, you can use the [DynamicData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.dynamicdataattribute?view=mstest-net-1.3.2) attribute in which you can specify a method or property which can retrieve non-constant data.

For example;

```
[DynamicData(nameof(GetTestData), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
[DataTestMethod]
public void TestFoo_Bar_ReturnsExpected(decimal x, decimal y, decimal expectedResult)
{
    var foo = new Foo();

    var outcome = foo.Bar(x, y);

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, outcome);
}

public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetTestData()
{
    yield return new object[] { 0M, 5M, 0M };
    yield return new object[] { 5M, 5M, 25M };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you are obviously making the method create the dates at a time after compile-time and the library does not let you do that.

You have two **solutions**:

1. Pass a **string** and than process it inside the method.
2. Pass **separate integers** (day, month, year etc.) and process them inside the method.